# Nested promoted interface methods becoming invisible

Tags: go

I'm working on an application that supports various physical devices of different capabilities (https://github.com/andig/evcc). The actual capabilities to expose to the application are defined by config.

The current code uses interfaces to determine if a specific device supports a capability, e.g.

```
if d.(MeterEnergy) ... // can call the MeterEnergy() method
```

Now a device can support any combination of capabilities (energy, power, current, voltage etc) and I'm trying to find a way to initialise such a device.

I've tried to achieve this my creating structs per capability where each type of struct implements a specific interface.
Additional capabilities are added as promoted interfaces like in https://play.golang.org/p/l9Xp_h8iWJo. Unfortunately this fails as only the methods of the static type and the first promoted interface are exposed, but nested promoted methods are discarded.

Is this by go design and is there an elegant workaround?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do sounds like trying to compose interfaces into structs at runtime. That will not work. First, let's look at what you have:

```
type Fooer interface{ Foo() }
type Barer interface{ Bar() }
type Bazer interface{ Baz() }

type fooer struct{}
func (i *fooer) Foo() { println("foo") }

type barer struct{ Fooer }
func (i *barer) Bar() { println("bar") }

type bazer struct{ Fooer }
func (i *bazer) Baz() { println("baz") }

func newFooer(bar, baz bool) Fooer {
    f := &fooer{}
    var foo Fooer = f
    if bar {
       b := &barer{foo}
       foo = b
    }
    if baz {
       b := &bazer{foo}
       foo = b
    }
   return foo
}
```

The return from the function is an instance of `fooer`, `barer`, or `bazer`. There is no type in the program that implements both `Barer` and `Bazer`, so what you are trying to do cannot happen.

Even with the part that works, with the `bazer` struct, you still have to initialize the `Fooer` implementation in the struct, because that is a member field of type `Fooer`, and you have to set it to an implementation of `Fooer`.

One way you can do this is using a fat interface:

```
type Fat struct {
   Foo Fooer
   Bar Barer
   Baz Bazer
}
```

Then, set the `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` to non-nil values if the device represented by the `Fat` struct supports those interfaces. Then you can also check:

```
func f(dev Fat) {
   if dev.Bar!=nil {
     // Device support Bar interface
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use behavioural testing for sake of elegance- using the !=nil approach would be last resort.

Comment: If you have a struct implementing multiple interfaces, you can do that. However, you cannot dynamically create a type by composing interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're conflating interfaces with struct embedding. What you're after?

If you want to have a way to construct a data type which contains certain fields (and may be method) use struct embedding, for instance:

```golang
type Energy struct {
 Level float64
}

func (e *Energy) SetLevel(lvl float64) {
  e.Level = lvl
}

type Current struct {
 Value float64
}

func (c *Current) SetValue(v float64) {
  c.Value = v
}

// A combined data type:

type CoolDevice struct {
  Energy
  Current
}

var dev CoolDevice

dev.SetLevel(42)
dev.SetValue(23)
```

If you are not interested in combining structs to create combined data types and are instead interested in having *combined interfaces to assert behaviour* of the values of those types, then combine interfaces:

```golang
type Energized interface {
 SetLevel(float64)
}


type Electronic interface {
 SetValue(float64)
}

// A combined interface type:

type EnergizedElectronic {
  Energized
  Electronic
}

var dev &CoolDevice{}

ee := dev.(EnergizedElectronic)
ee.SetLevel(42)
ee.SetValue(23)
```

Note that interfaces are fine to be ad hoc; this means that you do not need to predeclare a set of combined interfaces to cover the Cartezian product of the set of your individual interfaces; something like this is fine:

```golang
func TweakDevice(dev interface{}) {
  type wackyDev interface {
    EnergySetter
    VoltageSetter
  }

  if wd, ok := dev.(wackyDev); ok {
    wd.SomeEnergySetterMethod(42)
    wd.SomeVoltageSetterMethod(12)
  }

  ...
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that it's also fine to type-assert a variable of some concrete type describing your device to each from a set of narrow interfaces in turn, and operate through each of them.
Taking the former example, that could be

```golang
func TweakDevice(dev interface{}) {
  if es, ok := dev.(EnergySetter); ok {
    ws.SomeEnergySetterMethod(42)
  }

  if ws, ok := dev.(VoltageSetter); ok {
    ws.SomeVoltageSetterMethod(12)
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I've updated the goal above and created https://play.golang.org/p/BI7w-3hAlpm. I didn't know about runtime-combined interfaces. Problem also with the new play is still that the code needs to take all combinations into account.

Comment: Fixed a bug with the play in https://play.golang.org/p/0HYSuMKdIfE

Comment: I still can't quite grasp what you're after; this is mostly because we're discussing your attempted solution rather than a crisp definition of what you'd like to achieve in the first place ([the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)). Unfortunately, SO is absolutely unfit for discussion which require multiple back-and-forth exchanges, so could be please restart on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) or on [r/golang](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/)? Ideally, your post shold include "something" (it well could be some pseudo code)…

Comment: …which would show how you'd like to see your "devices" created and subsequently operated on. The chief issue for me is that I fail to see whether you have in mind a predefined set of concrete types—each of which represents a particular device,—or you need a "generic" way to create any (yet unforseen) kind of device which must combine a set of "functionality facets"—by specifying such set of facets at construction time. I recommend spending more words describing these things.